# Vote for what is "on-topic"?

Tags: feature-request

Who is responsible for the "[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" page? I think it would be great if users could have more control over this.

Would it be possible to let users vote for what should be considered on- and off-topic? Maybe once a year?

Comment: Users do have control, only in a different way- As we use the site, we see what works and what doesn't for the site, and the site adapts accordingly after various meta posts and discussions.

Comment: @Kendra is that really the best way? We do have moderator elections, what's the difference?

Comment: @ryanyuyu isn't it strange that there are great 'historical' questions that couldn't be asked today?

Comment: Do you have a specific question type in mind which should no longer be OT?

Comment: @laktak that's true and also a part of SO becoming more mature.  And adding to standards.  As for your feature request, I think it's unnecessary since those involved in SO can put in their own _specific_ request, which is then voted on by the community.  It's redundant to have another system.

Comment: @Plutonix of course but I don't think it would help this discussion.

Comment: @laktak It's a good way. It's worked since SO started. Why do you think voting on it would be better? What if between those points the community started feeling something was on-topic or off-topic again? Would they have to wait for the next topic votes? This is adaptable and dynamic, and it's worked not only here but on other sites in the network.

Comment: If we allowed everyone to vote about what is on-topic, I think we would have _write me the code_ in that list.

Comment: @Kendra OK, so maybe I don't understand how the current system works. Asking on Meta can change the on-topic page? Who is responsible for it?

Comment: @laktak You post your suggestion here on meta, a discussion ensues, opinions pro and contra are voiced, voting indicates general agreement or disagreement, time passes, changes happen.

Comment: @laktak The SE team maintains the page (I think mods might have access to change things in there too, but I don't know for sure.) After the discussions happen and things start changing, the page can be changed. If it doesn't get changed to reflect the current situation after a decent amount of time (the team is busy after all), it's okay to post a meta question asking for the page to be updated, highlighting exactly what is incorrect or missing.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this now: make a case on Meta for why something should or should not be within the scope of the site. See how the community responds to that. With enough support, these guidelines can be changed.

What is and is not on topic has significantly evolved over time since the founding of the site, largely due to community opinion. While Stack Exchange generally has final say on this, their actions tend to be guided by the community and what we've found to work on this site.

Comment: IMO that process could be improved. How many people bother to visit Meta vs SO?

Comment: @laktak Of the "active" users who really *care* about this site, a lot.

Comment: @laktak If no one bothers to visit Meta, what did you hope to accomplish by posting this question?

Comment: @ChrisBaker what other option would there be at the moment?

Comment: @laktak Where would you put that proposed topic-voting system of yours? It'd also be somewhere where not everyone goes...

Comment: @deceze advertising it the same way as the moderator elections?

Comment: @laktak I can sort of see how this *could* work, but practically I don't see it working. Moderator elections are a very clear cut, one-time, limited activity. However, what is on-topic and off-topic is a very delicate and nuanced discussions which takes time to resolve and lots of sampling of real world data in-between. It's not something you can simply vote on. You need to build consensus within the community over time based on observation.

Comment: @laktak Make a popular enough request and it will show up on "Hot Meta Posts", or a moderator could "feature" it (haven't actually seen that happen for normal posts, but there is always a first!). As others have said though, just post what you think *should* be on-topic and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Who would set the entries for the on/off topic vote?  There would have to be a vote on it...

It would be another bloodbath as deadbeat students try to get their plagiarized, uncompilable, unlinkable, unrunnable, untested and undebugged walls of utter hopeless shite accepted as on-topic.

Similarly, opinion based crap like library recommendations.

Similarly all the other stuff that floats around in the massive lake of sewage pressing on the dam of SO policy.

If cracks are allowed in the wall, SO is doomed.